# Unable to connect to Oracle Instance using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Dear Friends,
             I have an instance of Oracle 11g installed in my test m/c.In my development m/c have installed SQL developer.But I am unable to connect to DB although both machines are on the LAN and are accessible otherwise for folder sharing

The error message I get is 
"Test Failed :IO Error:The Network Adaptor could not establish the connection"

Although I am able to connect to DB when SQL developer is on same machine.
Thanks in advance for helping.

```html
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\enduser\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

    

 SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\enduser\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\enduser\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\enduser
```

```html
And TNSName.ora is 

# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\enduser\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.



>      

    LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.18.2.127)
    )
  )
```

Comment: is port 1521 opened for incoming connections?

Comment: I guess so, since I am able to connect with port 1521 when on the same machine

Comment: Also please let me know of any command for checking the port is open

Comment: open a command window and type `telnet hostname 1521`. Ports are usually blocked for inbound traffic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787934/firewall-blocking-unblocking-a-port

Comment: Thanks for the valuable hint, indeed I am unable  to connect to port 1521.I tried the steps mentioned in your link and added new rule for inbound traffic. But still get the 'unable to connect' result on telnet

Comment: do you have a proxy or external firewall that might block traffic? can you ping the remote system?

Comment: Sorry buddy, your message was hidden under 'show more'. Yes, I am able to ping the test machine ip.Have disabled firewall in the test machine and there is no proxy

Comment: besides restarting the windows firewall service or the whole machine I am out of ideas.

Comment: no problem... thanks for your comments so far